# Consolidate JQuery .focus script

Tags: jquery

I am curious what the best way would be to consolidate this stack of Jquery .focus functions.

Basically, I am using this to allow the URL to have the #ID on it, and when it does, Jquery updates the form that shows on the page.

What would the best way be to consolidate this so that I don't have to repeat the same code over and over?

Note, all the elements with ID's on them do have the same class on them.

Thanks, 
J

--

```
$('#select-1').focus(function(e) {
            // set the selected choice based on URL ID
            $category_select.val('1');
            updateSupport($categorychoice.val());
        });

    $('#select-2').focus(function(e) {
            // set the selected choice based on URL ID
            $category_select.val('billing');
            updateSupport($categorychoice.val());
        });

    $('#select-3').focus(function(e) {
            // set the selected choice based on URL ID
            $category_select.val('setup');
            updateSupport($categorychoice.val());
        });

    $('#select-4').focus(function(e) {
            // set the selected choice based on URL ID
            $category_select.val('errors');
            updateSupport($categorychoice.val());
        });

    $('#select-5').focus(function(e) {
            // set the selected choice based on URL ID
            $category_select.val('customization');
            updateSupport($categorychoice.val());
        });

    $('#select-6').focus(function(e) {
            // set the selected choice based on URL ID
            $category_select.val('6');
            updateSupport($categorychoice.val());
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not add an attribute (such as data-source-id="item id") to each 'select-?' element then you can use the css selector to attach the focus() and the attribute to determine which id it relates to ...

```
$(".myCssName").focus(....)

$category_select.val( $(this).data("source-id") )
```

*Edited with suggestion by kpblc*

Comment: agreed with you, but maybe better use "data" attribute?. so it will be $(this).data("source-id")

Answer (score 0):

Try using Object:

```
var values = {
  'select-1' : '1',
  'select-2' : 'billing',
  'select-3' : 'setup',
  'select-4' : 'errors',
  'select-5' : 'customization',
  'select-6' : '6'
};


$('[id^=select-]').on('focus', function(e) {
    $category_select.val(values[this.id]);
    updateSupport($categorychoice.val());
});
```